# Traveling on the surface of a hollow cylinder vs. a hollow sphere

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Cylindrical and spherical surfaces differ in many of their geometric/topological properties. For example, the cylinder has 0 Gaussian curvature while the sphere does not. Can someone help me formalize another statement about cylinders: that you can travel from the exterior to the interior of a cylindrical shell of finite length without "ripping" it, but you cannot do so on a spherical shell? What properties of cylinders/spheres do I need to invoke to make this distinction?

Comment: The cylinder is not a closed surface (it has boundary), so you can cross the boundary to get from the outside to the inside. You could do that with a hemisphere, as well. This has absolutely nothing to do with curvature.

Comment: I thought closed surfaces DID contain their boundaries; is that not correct?

Comment: The use of the language in higher mathematics is that a closed surface is a compact manifold without boundary. It's not referring to whether or not you have a closed topological subspace.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you!